# Strange e1550 dongle behavior, initialized only if loaded in Windows previously

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I'm a new user of Ubuntu, and connect to internet via **Huawei e1550** *dongle* (USB modem). I also have a Windows OS like a second one (dual boot) on my laptop. So yesterday I login to Windows, do some stuff .. Then re-login to Linux and dongle started working again. So I do some stuff, then suspend the system and go sleeping.

This morning I open laptop, but it was no connection. I try to re-plugging dongle, reboot the Linux, suspending, but all that stuff was useless. So I reboot it once again, go to windows, connect to internet, then again reboot to Ubuntu and now dongle work again.

So, why is that strange? And what should I do to be able use dongle in Ubuntu without previously loading windows?

---

lsusb output for device when working as a modem is like that:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
```

when I re-plugging it, it stop working again and lsusb input change to this:

```
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E1552/E1800 (HSPA modem)
```

So it makes me once again reload to Windows and then go back to Ubuntu to be able to connect to Internet.

Comment: Can you provide output from **`lsusb`**, for this device? eg. *What changes with the USB device connected, or not connected.* Also, does this change immediately after you connect the device?

Comment: Hi David. Please, check my updates.

Comment: Have you loaded *non-free* firmware support? **`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`**

Comment: No, I do not install it - should I do that? And how it could help - I check this package - it's a bunch of drivers. Maybe I could install something standalone?

Comment: This provides 'firmware' to load to the USB modem, and not having this available may be causing your problems. Look at output from **`dmesg`**. *There may be error messages that confirm this.*